# start eclipse error, start to "Loading org.eclipse.core.filebuffers"

Tags: java, eclipse

today, i in the console execute end eclipse process. now run eclipse is not start. start in the "Loading org.eclipse.core.filebuffers" stop start alos tip "java heap space" [image: Error Message]

workspace logs file content is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-05 13:55:59.305
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledTextRenderer.setStyleRanges(StyledTextRenderer.java:1228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.setStyleRanges(StyledText.java:9913)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.setStyleRanges(StyledText.java:9976)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.applyTextPresentation(TextViewer.java:4884)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.changeTextPresentation(TextViewer.java:4936)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler.applyTextRegionCollection(PresentationReconciler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler.processDamage(PresentationReconciler.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler.access$3(PresentationReconciler.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.presentation.PresentationReconciler$InternalListener.textChanged(PresentationReconciler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.updateTextListeners(TextViewer.java:2826)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.invalidateTextPresentation(TextViewer.java:3478)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(AbstractTextEditor.java:4628)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(JavaEditor.java:2519)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.handlePreferenceStoreChanged(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$PropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(AbstractTextEditor.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.firePropertyChangeEvent(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.handlePropertyChangeEvent(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore.access$0(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ChainedPreferenceStore$PropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(ChainedPreferenceStore.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore$3.run(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:351)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-12-05 13:59:31.266
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.dispose(WorkbenchPart.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.ExtendedMarkersView.dispose(ExtendedMarkersView.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.invalidate(CompatibilityPart.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.destroy(CompatibilityPart.java:394)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:159)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-12-05 13:59:31.269
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
```

if you konw ,place tell me .
                                                                 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to increase heap size of the eclipse

1. Go to Eclipse Folder
2. Edit `eclipse.ini`
3. Set\increase the heap memory size like below

   ```
   -startup
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
   --launcher.library
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
   -showsplash
   org.eclipse.platform
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256m
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   -vmargs
   -Xms512m
   -Xmx1024m
   -XX:+UseParallelGC
   -XX:PermSize=256M
   -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about modifying these parameters before. I used to solve the problem after your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The above error is due to out of space of java heap memory are, you can increase your java heap size using :
[image]

Go to the **Run** icon and select **Run Configurations**
[image]
Select **Arguments** and Specify head size in **VM Arguments**.
eg: `Xmx1024`

Comment: My problem has been solved. Thank you again for your reply.